# Не срабатывает js функция на html странице

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, веб-программирование, golang

Всем доброго дня. 
Решил тут попробовать сделать web-сервер на Go. 
В отдельном файле лежат данные в JSON формате, и по идее они должны выводиться на страницу.

[image: Иерархия проекта]

Но вместо этого выводится только рамка. Прошу помочь/подсказать, где ошибка.

main.go

```
    package main 
    import (
        "html/template"
        "log"
        "net/http"
    )

    var tpl template.Template
    func init() {
        tpl = template.Must(template.ParseGlob("templates/.html"))
    }
```

```
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", indexPage)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil))
}

func indexPage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    err := tpl.Execute(w, "index.html")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
}
```

index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <style>
        .cards {
            border: 1px solid red;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            padding: 20px;
        }
        .card {
            border: 1px solid blue;
            padding: 5px;
            width: 100%;
        }
        .card__id {
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        .card__name {
            font-style: italic;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="cards"> </div>
        <script>

function card({ id, name }) {
    return `
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card__id">${id}</div>
            <div class="card__name">${name}</div>
        </div>
    `;
};

const container = document.querySelector('.cards');
window.container = container;
fetch('/api/users.json')
    .then(users => users.json())
    .then(users => {
        container.innerHTML = users.map(card).join('');
    });
        </script>

    </body>
</html>

JSON файл, из которого берутся данные:

[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Олег"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Мария"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Афанасий"
    }
]

Comment: Откройте консоль разработчика в браузере и посмотрите как выглядит итоговая html страница вместе с JS-скриптом.

Answer (score 0):

Добавил еще один handler в main. Полёт нормальный

```
func main() {
http.HandleFunc("/", indexPage)
http.HandleFunc("/api/users.json", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    http.ServeFile(w, r, r.URL.Path[1:])
})
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil))
}
```